# Convert String to Date in Tableau using DATEPARSE

Tags: date, tableau-api, date-parsing

Trying to convert string "12/30/19 01:40:31" into a short date field in Tableau. I can't figure out the correct way to do the "DATEPARSE" format?  Any help?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set the field as a Date type, and then use the built-in date formatting option to display it as a short date.
If Tableau is not identifying the field as a date type, right click on the field in the left-hand pane, and select Change Data Type and select Date.
To get the short date format, right click on the field in the left-hand pane, and select Default Properties -> Date Format.

If you need to use DATEPARSE, here is an example:

```
DATEPARSE('dd-MM-YY', [myDateField])
```

Comment: Thanks for your help..  I get an error about communicating with the data server. I have a Oracle SQL query wrote into the Tableau report.

Comment: If you're getting an error, you should update your question and add in the text of the error, and explain what triggers the error.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you don't need a calculated field here.
On your date dimension -> click on the drop down button -> default properties -> date format -> custom type "mm/dd/yy".

You can refer the doc [here](https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/dates_custom_date_formats.htm)